# Redirecting http=>https (non-www) + www https=> non-www https (no certificate for www)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have seen many articles on rewrites. All good. But none covering this exact situation. So here is my question: hope you can help. Because I cannot get it to work.

- we run website on domain.com (non-www)
- we have ssl set up (so https only)
- we have 1 certificate for the non-www version (not www version)

When we execute all four test cases, 3 are OK, 1 not

1. http://domain.com => https://domain.com =>
2. http://www.domain.com => https://domain.com => oK
3. https://domain.com => OK
4. https://www.domain.com => ERROR. Certificate warning not safe

**Question**: Now why is number 4 https://www giving me this error. I would expect the first rule to pick-up and send us to the non-www version. And how do I fix this?

Appreciate any help ;P Sean

---

This is my currect htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  # Redirect www to non-www first 
  # Added based on article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%1/$1 [R=301,NE,L]

  # Then redirect http to https (if necessary)
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You need a wildcard certificate, but I will help you out here. Try to remove the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` and `</IfModule>` and tell me if you get any error 500.

Comment: Problem is this is already a multi domain certificate, so this means I would have to add every www. version of ALL the domains separately? I don't know any wildcard multidomain certificates

Comment: Wildcard certificates are a special type where the name of the host is `*.example.com` instead of `example.com`. This allows you to use the certificate for **ALL** your subdomains. (It **WON'T** work for subdomains like `another.cool.example.com`. For that, you need a wildcard certificate *per*  sub-domain.) `www` may be seen as a subdomain (it usually is mapped to the folder `www`, which might have/be a link to `public_html`).

Comment: Try this instead of the last part: `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)   RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]` (split it by lines, I can't do it in a comment).

Comment: Actually, the first check should be `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^off$`. I've tested it on http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and it seems to work.

Comment: >> Actually, the first check should be RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^off$ - no this is not correct. Because when then opening www.domain.com it goes to https://www.domain.com (it is not splitting of the www). This should be done first

Comment: And i conclusion (reading the other links) the https://www to https://non-www is just not possible without an extended certificate

Comment: When I said "`Actually, the first check should be RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^off$`", I was refering to my previous comment. I couldn't edit because the comments gets 'locked' after 5 minutes.

Comment: Maybe a solution? The problem is that https://www is serving a certificate and this make the handshake occur BEFORE the htacces redirect. Suppose we would have a way to DISABLE the SSL on the www version of the website? This way there is NO handshake and the directe is executed

Comment: I don't think it will work as you expect. You can try to ask about it on http://serverfault.com/ (you only have to login, loke how you do here). They will be a much better help. Also, try Croises' answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible to solve only by htaccess or nginx conf.

One needs a certificate to cover both the www and non www version of the domain

So a wildcard cert or a multidomain cert where both www and non www are included as a separate domain

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

You can use this in your .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  # Redirect www to non-www first 
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%1/$1 [R=301,NE,L]

  # Then redirect http to https (if necessary)
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

But there's nothing you can do for certificate error.
Read: [Redirecting https://www to https://non-www - without seeing certificate error, possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27673013/redirecting-https-www-to-https-non-www-without-seeing-certificate-error-p)