# Redirect All Requests to Https with 'www'

Tags: .htaccess, https

I have certificate for www.example.com

It's working for now.

I want to redirect all requests with 'www' and non 'www' **to** https with 'www'

1. `http://www.example.com to https://www.example.com`
2. `http://example.com to https://www.example.com`
3. `https://example.com to https://www.example.com`

I am getting error that, 'Certificate is only valid for www.example.com'

How can i make redirections?

What i tried?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

It's working on chrome. 
On firefox https://example.com is giving error that.

**Your connection isn't secure**.

I tried to clear history and cache for firefox. It's quite same.

Comment: cert warning cannot be fixed by redirect rules.

Comment: it's working on chrome and chrome mobile, it doesn't work on firefox and samsung mobile.

Comment: Is this a self certified certificate? Depending on the Encryption level and the version of your browser, one browser might accept a certification while the other will not. For instance, IE 11 will take a 1024 bit encrypted certificate while FireFox and Chrome will say the certificate is insecure.

Comment: To remove the cert warning, You need to buy a valid certificate for your non-www domain. Read more on this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/27673113/3160747

Comment: I use letsencrypt. And it's secured. Created new certifcate for non www. Now it is giving error for https :// www.example.com

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

Generated 1 certificate for 2 domains example.com and www.example.com

https://gethttpsforfree.com/

Followed instruction at here.
Used that in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

And yay yay. 
All variants are working for all browsers including mobile.